# Limitations of Filters to search data

Tags: neo4j-ogm

I am exploring how I can write generic query for any Node given a set of search parameters and came across `org.neo4j.ogm.cypher.Filters` (in `neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.3.jar`)

I would have liked to have more options for `ComparisionOperator` like `CONTAINS`, `IN`, `STARTSWITH` etc.

Right now the operators supported are:

- `EQUALS("=")`
- `MATCHES("=~")`
- `LIKE("=~", new CaseInsensitiveLikePropertyValueTransformer())`
- `GREATER_THAN(">")`
- `LESS_THAN("<")`

Are there is any plan to enhance this to support more operations?

Here is an example of how I am using `Filters`:

```
public Collection<User> findUserByFirstNameLike(String firstName) {
    Filters filters = new Filters();
    Filter firstNameFilter = new Filter("firstName", firstName);
    firstNameFilter.setComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LIKE);
    filters.add(firstNameFilter);
    Collection<User> users = session.loadAll(User.class, filters);
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Filters` has been updated in `neo4j-ogm-core` version `2.1.0`.

All 3 options you want to see (`CONTAINS`, `IN`, `STARTS WITH`) are available in this version along with:

- `LESS_THAN("<")`
- `LESS_THAN_EQUAL("<=")`
- `IS_NULL("IS NULL")`
- `ENDING_WITH("ENDS WITH")`
- `EXISTS("EXISTS")`
- `IS_TRUE("=")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helps. Would you have any test cases in github for usage of Filters. I am trying to figure out how to use it to query on a relationship.

Comment: Check out: `RelationshipQueryStatementsTest`, `NodeQueryStatementsTest`, `RestaurantIntegrationTest` and `FilterTest` in the OGM: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I want to write cypher queries as much as possible using api based approach rather than having each developer having to write @Query. Is is possible to use Filter to query on 2nd level relationship. eg : I have User -> Role -> Priviledge and I want to search Users that have a certain priviledge. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504620/graphrepository-find-method-on-2nd-level-relationship/

Comment: At this stage no.  We will hopefully add this at some stage in the future to bring the functionality in line with other Spring Data projects.